# php , creating a new attribute in sql results array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

The following code keeps returning the error

> Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object

This happens during the line $a->tomorrowDate = array("dateTomorrow" => $invoiceNextDay);

```
foreach ($resultInvoices as &$a) {
                $invoiceDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $a['date']);
                $invoiceNextDay = $invoiceDate->modify('+1 day');
                $invoiceNextDay->format('Ymd');
                $a->tomorrowDate = array("dateTomorrow" => $invoiceNextDay);
                $a['date']=$invoiceDate->format('Ymd');
            }
```

What is wrong with that line?

Comment: What is `dateTomorrow`, a constant, a string?

Comment: I believe its a constant.

Comment: it was originally $a->tomorrowDate = $invoiceNextDay but still had the same error.

Comment: So you have two constants right now. Both `tomorrowDate` and `dateTomorrow`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue.

```
 foreach ($resultInvoices as &$a) {
                $invoiceDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $a['date']);
                $a['date']=$invoiceDate->format('Ymd');
                $invoiceNextDay = $invoiceDate->modify('+1 day');
                $invoiceNextDay->format('Ymd');
                $a['tomorrowDate'] = $invoiceNextDay;
            }
```

Essentially, what I tried before was for objects, whilst now, its specific to arrays. $a['tomorrowDate'] = $invoiceNextDay; This will create a new element in the array with attribute tomorrowDate and then assign it the value.